# What is the jq equivalent for the slurp option?

Tags: jq, collect

This generates a list of arrays:

```
$ echo -e "a 1\nb 2" | jq -R 'split(" ")'
[
  "a",
  "1"
]
[
  "b",
  "2"
]
```

When I slurp the input I get an array:

```
$ echo -e "a 1\nb 2" | jq -R 'split(" ")' | jq -s .
[
  [
    "a",
    "1"
  ],
  [
    "b",
    "2"
  ]
]
```

But when I try to convert the list into an array without slurping it, I get a list of arrays instead of a single array:

```
$ echo -e "a 1\nb 2" | jq -R '[split(" ")]'
[
  [
    "a",
    "1"
  ]
]
[
  [
    "b",
    "2"
  ]
]
```

Is it possible to slurp the result of the `split` without piping the result into a new instance of `jq`?

Comment: https://github.com/stedolan/jq/issues/684#issuecomment-72089629

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Before the advent of `inputs`, the answer to the question was "No".  With `inputs` and the -n command-line option:

```
$ echo -e "a 1\nb 2" | jq -nR '[inputs|split(" ")]' 
[
  [
    "a",
    "1"
  ],
  [
    "b",
    "2"
  ]
]
```

Answer (score -1):

With *double* `split`:

```
echo -e "a 1\nb 2" | jq -sR 'split("\n")[:-1] | map(split(" "))'
```

The output:

```
[
  [
    "a",
    "1"
  ],
  [
    "b",
    "2"
  ]
]
```

Comment: I know I can use the slurp option. But I was asking, if something equivalent exists as a `jq` expression.